# Live streaming and processing of CZML Packets in cesium

Tags: streaming, live, cesiumjs, czml

Hi how to stream live czml packets and process in java script without making UI freeze and without starting the scenario from the begining, whenever i send new czml packet of an object from server with new updated Cartesian coordinates along with epoch time and elapsed seconds from epoch time , the whole scenario will restarts from the beginning after processing the packet. So how to avoid scenario restart. Basically i want object in the scenario moving with real time , where real time Cartesian coordinates are fed from server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are calling `CzmlDataSource.load` or `CzmlDataSource.loadUrl` each time.  This causes existing data to be removed.  If you simply want to update data, call `CzmlDataSource.process` or `CzmlDataSource.processUrl`.

Also, when you construct the Viewer, be sure to pass the `automaticallyTrackDataSourceClocks` option and set it to `false`. This will prevent automatic clock adjustment based on loaded data.

Comment: Thank you very much Matthew. Actually i was processing the czml packet using the CzmlDataSource.process only, but the mistake i was doing was adding the dataSource object again and again as and when i processed. so that was causing the scenario to reset. Thanks for your valuable time. I will certainly try you next suggestion about constructing the Viewer.